# Collapse single column cell under parent row in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

The report displays a row for applications made by a user, one column contains free form text. This unlike the other values spreads across multiple lines and so makes the report messy with random row height for each record.

Is there a way to make this one column cell for each record collapsible, where a lil' "+" appears to click to display the cells contents?

The basic query pulling the data through is straight from a table, just with where limitations and an order by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EON_Evidence_Review

WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [Recieved On], 103) > @CutOffDate
    AND [Completed By] IS NOT NULL 
    AND [Date Completed] IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY 
    [Recieved On], 
    [Date Completed] DESC, 
    [Display Name]
```

Comment: do you have any sample code ?

Comment: @Mitrucho Its being pulled straight from a table, just with where limitations and an order by, I've added the simple select to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done that using groups.
It's all explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220405.aspx

Comment: This hides the entire column or displays the entire column, this is fine but ideally I want to be able to show or hide a single cell at a time. So the row always remains but for each row theres a "+" which makes the text of the cell for that column expand.

Comment: Ok, you can right click on the textbox -> Text Box Properties -> Visibility -> Display can be toggled by this report item. Then select the previous item on the list. You'll get the "+" toggle.